# Broken Ubuntu after failed apt upgrade

Tags: 16.04, boot

I dual booted my computer a while back, but a BIOS update broke grub and I didn't bother to fix it until recently. When I finally did (kernel issue), I ran `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` as per usual to get my packages to the most recent version. However, my entire desktop froze 78% through the installation step.

Now, my Ubuntu can't boot at all. It tries to boot as normal, but on the login page, there is only an orangeish background with dots, which is not my normal background. Also, there is no bar at the top of my screen with wireless or anything, it's just gone. However, I can log in, but doing so just brings me to a black screen with my mouse cursor, nothing else.

My main problem is that I can't go to a terminal screen, ctrl + alt + F1 does nothing.

I'm running a dual booted Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 10 machine.

Comment: Are you able to get into [RecoveryMode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode)?

Comment: What was the last line printed in the terminal before it froze?

Comment: @fakedad I can get into RecoveryMode, but I can't connect to my network while there to reinstall packages. @Organic Marble The last line of the terminal was something along the lines of `Installing for Intel x86_64...`